# Replace <img> src and decode <a> href

Tags: php

I want to transform the following:

```
1. From:
<img class="lazyjs bbcodeImage" src="//google.com/blank.gif" data-original="http://google.com/poster.jpg" alt="image" />

1. To:
<img src="http://domain.com/poster.jpg" />

2. From:
<a rel="nofollow" href="/confirm/url/aHR0cDovL2dvb2dsZS5jb20%3D/" class="ajaxLink">

2. To:
<a href="http://google.com">
```

Basically, I want to use the `data-original` for `<img src`. The `<a href` is first encoded with `base64_encode`, then with `urlencode`.

Here's what I've done at until now:

```
<?php
// 1
$string = '<img class="lazyjs bbcodeImage" src="//google.com/blank.gif" data-original="http://google.com/poster.jpg" alt="image" />';

echo preg_replace('/<img class="lazyjs bbcodeImage" src="\/\/google.com\/blank.gif" data-original="(.*?)" alt="image" \/>/', '<img src="$1" />', $string);

// 2
$string = '<a rel="nofollow" href="/confirm/url/aHR0cDovL2dvb2dsZS5jb20%3D/" class="ajaxLink">';

echo preg_replace('/<a rel="nofollow" href="\/confirm\/url\/(.*?)\/" class="ajaxLink">/', '<a href="$1">', $string);
?>
```

The problem is that on `2` I don't know how to decode the `$1`.

Comment: Take a look at: `preg_replace_callback()`

Answer (score 0):

There will probably be people suggesting `regex`, but according to [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) that is not a proper solution. Thank god somebody made  [PHPquery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). This way you can use selectors like you are used to in jQuery to select these attributes.

Comment: If you're talking about the JavaScript's jQuery library - this is a PHP Non-HTML application, so I have to stick with the PHP only.

Comment: No it's a port from the javascript version to PHP, that's why it's call PHPquery....

Comment: Is it fast? I'm talking about 10,000,000 queries per day. I really don't want to include any class, but if this is the only way...

Comment: @TurboHost 10 milion isn't a lot for computers nowadays. But you can still use regex if you want, I guess it is acceptable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think I did it:

```
<?php
// 1
$string = '<img class="lazyjs bbcodeImage" src="//google.com/blank.gif" data-original="http://google.com/poster.jpg" alt="image" />';

echo preg_replace('/<img class="lazyjs bbcodeImage" src="\/\/google.com\/blank.gif" data-original="(.*?)" alt="image" \/>/', '<img src="$1" />', $string);

// 2
$string = '<a rel="nofollow" href="/confirm/url/aHR0cDovL2dvb2dsZS5jb20%3D/" class="ajaxLink">';

echo preg_replace_callback('/<a rel="nofollow" href="\/confirm\/url\/(.*?)\/" class="ajaxLink">/', function ($match) { return '<a href="' . base64_decode(urldecode($match[1])) . '">'; }, $string);
?>
```

Comment: Exactly, with `preg_replace_callback()` you can also apply callback functions to your matches.